# Why doesn't this Regex code work for a P.O. Box string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I am trying to check if a string is a P.O. Box. I have tested my Regex string with 2 different web browsers and it works just fine. When I use it as shown I cannot get a match.

```
NSString *string = @"P.O. Box 123";
NSString *regexString = @"/\\b[P]\\W*?\\s*?\\.*?\\s*?[o]\\W?\\s*?\\.*?\\s*?(st|stal)?\\W*?\\s*?(box|office) /igm";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
if ([expression numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:range] > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Matches");
}
```

Comment: What means the ` /igm` at the end? case insensitive, global and multiline? Remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the regex delimiters and options from the *string pattern*. `m` modifier is not necessary as you do not have `^` and `$` anchors inside and the `g` modifier is meant by default when used with `numberOfMatchesInString`.

Use

```
NSString *regexString = @"\\b[P]\\W*?\\s*?\\.*?\\s*?[o]\\W?\\s*?\\.*?\\s*?(st|stal)?\\W*?\\s*?(box|office) ";
```

Also note that in most cases here you may replace lazy quantifiers with greedy ones. `\W*?\s*?` can be successfully merged into `\W*` as `\W` matches whitespaces, too. E.g. this will work, too:

```
NSString *regexString = @"\\bP\\W*o\\W?\\s*\\.*\\s*(st|stal)?\\W*(box|office) ";
```

See [online Objective-C demo](http://ideone.com/ez18L4)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect!